# parallelize genetic algorithm with numba (cuda)

Tags: python, gpu, genetic-algorithm, numba

I am making a genetic algorithm on neural nets playing snake for educational purposes

**I want to be able to run my python code on my gpu** (cuda enabled) in order to save some time and accelerate the process.

The principle of my code is pretty simple, my genetic algorithm is a global loop where at each iteration I need to evaluate every neural network of my population

```
while(some_condition):
  # ...
  game = Game()
  for i in range(len(self.networks)):
      self.networks[i].score = game.start(network=self.networks[i])
  # ...
```

As you can see, I make an instance of a game (which is a class that I made) and for each neural net in my population, I start the game with it and put its score (function of the snake length and age) in an attribute

This is clearly the part in my GA that requires the most processing time: *playing games*.
Actually I make each neural net play four games to take an average score but for the sake of simplicity let think with only one

I've already parallelized it using python multiprocessing as follow:

```
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
while(some_condition):
  # ...
  game = Game()
  results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(game.start)(network=self.networks[i]) for i in range(len(self.networks)))
  # ...
```

It saves a lot of time as it uses all cores of my CPU but it is still slow and anyway I would like to start learning how to use GPU for such problems.

Can I consider using numba and cuda for my problem ? Is the structure of my problem relevant to GPU programming ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: GPUs are really good at solving matrix problems.  How does this fit that bill?  Multiprocessing(what you're doing) or refactoring might be a better solution.

Comment: Can I hope to use my GPU to multiprocess with numba as I did above for my CPU ?

Answer (score 0):

Anything for a.i. can be related to GPGPU. Here is example of rendering Mona Lisa out of circles using CUDA, some GPUs and genetic algorithm:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRZqBLJ6brQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65mddQc1VF8

It looks like Mona Lisa after just 10 minutes and by only 384(192+192) slow CUDA pipelines and fully-free circles or 2 minutes and independent circles.

The only difference (I guess from your codes) is the language (C++ in videos) that is not much difference if GPU computation is intense (instead of just drawing circles).

If all parts of genetic algorithm is in CUDA kernel, language is not important at all, just annotate the (to-be-cuda) Python functions with Numba-specific keywords. But when you sort things on host environment, then expect some performance difference.